# How to get my string repeated x times?

Tags: haskell

I'm a complete noob to Haskell I cant get my code working at all and i have no clue on how to fix it! I need help :) If someone has an idea of where i need to look in order to fix my issue i would be extremly greatful for ideas and nudges in the right direction.

I am trying to create a type of C# string.Format that repeats until a list is finished. The list is created by the userinput and then i just want a string to be repeated untill the list is finished.

```
    test :: Integer -> String
    let list_n [0..k]
    test k = putStrLn (r * r) | r <- list_n   --My idea here is that i am forcing 
    --the entire list onto r and making it repeated as long as there is more in the
    --list, But im not even sure that is possible :(
```

Anyone has a better idea on how to do this? I want all the results in a line and not a row therefore im trying to create ittereration but in HaskeLL that is easier said then done :/

Comment: Have you read any tutorials? e.g. [LYaH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) or [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/). (For one, your syntax for `let` is wrong, you aren't using list comprehension correctly, and `putStrLn` *prints* a string to a terminal, it doesn't make a string.)

Comment: I must have been reading the wrong things :/

Comment: I think your code should read `test k = [putStrLn $ r * r | r <- [0..k]]` but I don't actually understand what you're asking for

Comment: Can you give examples of what output `test` should generate given various inputs. i.e. what should be the value of `test 0`, what should be the value of `test 1`, of `test 2`, `test 3`?

Comment: Haskell is not a language that you're going to get just by playing around without reading carefully.  You really, really need to work with one of the books that dbaupp mentions.  I recommend *Learn You a Haskell* first, but if you finish and you feel like more, you should read the second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two proposals; one tries to match the code you posted, and the other tries to match the English you posted. This seems to be mostly a question about syntax, so I'm not sure there's a lot of meaningful explanation that can go along with this other than "read a tutorial".

```
-- match the code
test :: Int -> String
test k = concat [show (r * r) | r <- [0..k]]

-- match the English
test :: Int -> String -> String
test k s = concat [s | r <- [0..k]]
```

Comment: An alternate form of the English version is `test k = concat . replicate k`

Comment: @pat, or even `test = (concat .) . replicate`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that is closer to the imperative style:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

test :: Int -> IO ()
test n = forM_ [0..n] (\i -> putStrLn $ show $ i*i)
```

This translates roughly into: "for each i in [0..n], do ..."

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you mean to print a given string `n` times, and you appear to want to start a newline with each string, and you seem to want to use a list comprehension, which would be

```
test :: Integer -> String -> IO ()
test n xs = sequence_ [putStrLn xs| i<- [1..n]]
```

but you'd be throwing away the integers `i` you calculated. You'd be better to do

```
test n xs = replicateM_ n (putStrLn xs)
```

which gives

```
Main> test 3 "Hello"
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Perhaps you meant to show the numbers themselves as strings, which would be

```
test n = sequence_ [putStrLn (show i)| i<- [1..n]]
```

but again, it would be nicer to do

```
test n = mapM_ putStrLn (map show [1..n])
```

These two give

```
Main> test 3
1
2
3
```

But mainly, what you need to do is follow a good introductory text first. I'd recommend [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

It would help enormously if you edited your question to make it clearer what you wanted. What output did you want?